# how to use functions without conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to play a sound in html.

I putted `audio` tag in html and define a function to `play` it

but when I use the `.play()` function of js, the jquery return an error.

```
audio.play() is not a function.
```

when I remove jquery file, the sound is working.

how can I clear that the function is not jquery's?

```
function playblop()
    {
        var ab = document.getElementById('blop').play();
    }
```

Comment: How did you "define a function to `play` it"?

Comment: You need to cut down your code to a failing example that's small enough to post here.  It's unlikely that anyone will be able to help without seeing your code.

Comment: can you show us your scripts ?

Comment: I cant use the play function of js either

Comment: Can you show us how "blop" is placed in the HTML?

Comment: JS _has no `play` function_.  Some JS objects _may_ have a method called `play`.  If your `<audio>` element doesn't have it, you're on an unsupported browser.  jQuery **does not** remove methods from native element objects.

Comment: Please update your question with what browser you use to test, and what JS libraries, or jQuery plugins are included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put audio tag on autoplay...

every time you need to play, append the tag...

```
$("body").append("<audio autoplay>...</audio>");
```

Answer (score -1):

use a static object as namespace e.g.

```
    var myobject = {
        playblop: function(){

        }
    };
    //call the function
    myobject.playblop();
```

Updated: 
Ignore the code about and read this:
[HTML5 Audio and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588934/html5-audio-and-jquery)